# Поиск в многомернном массиве значения одного мерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива :

```
    $paramsCatID = array(
    '0'=> '1',
    '1'=> '2',
    '2'=> '3',
);
$allCatID = array(
    '0'=> array ('category_id'=>"1"),
    '1'=> array ('category_id'=>"2"),
    '2'=> array ('category_id'=>"3"),
    '3'=> array ('category_id'=>"4"),
    '4'=> array ('category_id'=>"5"),
    '5'=> array ('category_id'=>"6"),
    '6'=> array ('category_id'=>"7"),
);
```

Как мне вывести значения из второго массива `$allCatID` зная значения в первом массиве `$paramsCatID`.

То есть вывестись должно :

```
    $allCatID = array(
    '0'=> array ('category_id'=>"1"),
    '1'=> array ('category_id'=>"2"),
    '2'=> array ('category_id'=>"3"),
);
```

Comment: цикл по второму массиву с проверкой in_array в первом

Comment: Можешь перевести пример а то что то у меня мозг не врубается как написать. Извилинами понимаю а написать не получается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($allCatID as $key=>$arr){
    foreach($arr as $categoryId=>$value){
        if (in_array($value,$paramsCatID)){
            print_r($allCatID[$key][$categoryId]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array_map(function($i) { return array('category_id'=>$i); },
                  array_intersect(
                      array_map(function($i) {return $i['category_id']; },                                $allCatID), 
                                $paramsCatID)));
```